# How can activity tell its fragments that location is available so they update contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

This is more of a design question.

So I have a bottom navigation Activity (which has multiple fragments). One of the fragments (the one that loads by default) has textview which will display the location information of the user.

When the activity starts, it does the googleApiClient connect and request the location permission from the user. By the time the user accepts and all this is done, the fragment is loaded and the textview is showing "unknown location". Which is all expected.

Now when the location is acquired( after the user has accepted), what would be the right way to pass this information down to the fragment and tell the textview to update?

I can do polling (meaning keep checking the location if it is not null in a handler timer) but I feel this is not the right approach.

Any hint on how something like that is done would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: do it via an interface class

Comment: You can create a custom listener by interface. If the Location is gathered, listen it and then trigger it in your related fragment to change the text.

Comment: This is activity to fragment communication, can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver)

Comment: Thanks guys. So should it be an interface or just activity going through "fragments" that should hear about it?  an answer would be appreciated so I can accept it.

Comment: @Snake the interface way is for fragment to activity communication, but you need call method from fragment inside the activity. just check the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define appropriate method in your fragment, for instance

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

    public void changeLocationField(Location location){

    }
}
```

Then in the activity, call your method from fragment

```
private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.a_fragment);

        if (fragmentA != null) {
            fragmentA.changeLocationField(location);
        }
    }
};
```